# make a duplicate node in Jtree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i want to make a duplicate node in Jtree but the code is not working inside mouse action listener....

```
/* DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
      def obj = selectedNode.getUserObject()
      DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)node.getRoot().getChildAt(0);
      model.insertNodeInto(selectedNode, parentNode, 0)*/
```

Comment: This might be obvious, but that code is commented out.  If it's like that in your actual JS file then it's not going to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a call to "new" anywhere in this code.  Did I miss it?  Wouldn't that be a requirement or creating a new Node?

Create a new DMTN and initialize it with the state of the one you want to copy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not making a copy, you just try to insert the (existing) node into a different location.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
def obj = selectedNode.getUserObject()
DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)node.getRoot().getChildAt(0);
model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(obj), parentNode, 0);
```

(Obvious syntax errors have not been corrected, I am not your compiler.)